# Featured On Meta section doesn't list MSE posts on meta sites

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, community-bulletin, featured-tag

The **Featured on Meta** section of the Community Bulletin on a per-site Meta only lists its own featured posts, while the section on a main site also lists the featured MSE posts. Is it by-design? Any specific reason for this? I think it should be displayed.

Community Bulletin on a Main site:

[image: screenshot of main site]

Community Bulletin on a Meta site:

[image: screenshot of meta site]

Comment: They appear on top of the "frequently asked" questions instead, but I'm not sure that's the better behaviour.

Comment: @TimStone Are you sure? [Me and Glorfindel](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285631/featured-mse-posts-are-not-listed-in-the-sidebar-of-child-meta-sites?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment939403_285631) haven't seen that behaviour yet.

Comment: Related: [Nathaniel's answer to "Include questions from Meta SE in the "Hot Network Questions." (Or in the Community Bulletin network-wide)"](/a/280512/997587)