# Featured MSE posts are not listed in the sidebar of child Meta sites

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, sidebar

Stack Overflow currently shows two featured posts in the sidebar under *Featured on Meta*:

- MSE: A proposed philosophy of question migration
- MSO: Documentation Update, September 29th

Meta Stack Overflow only shows one featured post:

- MSO: Documentation Update, September 29th

Can you make it list MSE posts as well? I'm tagging this as a bug, but not sure whether it's intentionally missing.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236744/295232)?

Comment: @Glorfindel Ah, possibly yes. I hadn't found that one before.

Comment: @Glorfindel Although I'm not sure if Time Stone's comment is still correct (could be due to caching currently): *"They appear on top of the "frequently asked" questions instead, but I'm not sure that's the better behaviour. "*

Comment: No, that's not true. The 'Frequently Asked' sidebar module on MSO shows only MSO questions. I've never seen MSE questions there.