# Featured questions from meta.SE are not shown in community bulletin on per-site-metas

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, community-bulletin

I have tried several sites and noticed that [community bulletin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-bulletin/info) is displayed differently on the main site and on the local meta. The difference being that the community bulletin on the local meta does not contain [featured questions from meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured).

This question is currently featured: [New top bar is coming to the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300829). So it should be in the community bulletin if I correctly understood the description here: [How are the contents of the Community Bulletin determined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130621)

Here is what I see when I view CB on a main site:

[image: Screenshot form Mathematics]

And here is what I see in CB on the corresponding meta:

[image: Screenshot from Mathematics Meta]

I have tried several sites and this seems to be consistent behavior. (Perhaps other users can confirm whether this happens to them too. Maybe there might be some reasons why this could be specific to me - some caching issue or A/B-testing or something else.)

I have tried also to save this in Wayback Machine to confirm, but it seems that for unregistered users the community bulletin is displayed differently - currently it contains only the blog post: [main](http://web.archive.org/web/20170917072112/https://math.stackexchange.com/questions) and [meta](http://web.archive.org/web/20170917072152/https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: Now I found two older posts about the same problem: [Featured On Meta section doesn't list MSE posts on meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236744) and [Featured MSE posts are not listed in the sidebar of child Meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285631).