# The order of "Upcoming Events" and "The Overflow Blog" sections is swapped between Main and Meta sites in the Community Bulletin

Tags: feature-request, design, per-site-meta, community-bulletin

The order of items appearing in the Community Bulletin on Main sites and Meta sites is sometimes different: if a blog post as well as an upcoming event appear on the bulletin, then on Main sites the blog post appears first, followed by the upcoming event, and the other way around on the corresponding Meta.

For example, here's what the community bulletins on [Mathematics Main](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and [Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/) look like right now:

> [image: Community Bulletin on Mathematics Main, with The Overflow Blog on top]
> [image: Community Bulletin on Mathematics Meta, with the Upcoming Events on top]

**Feature request:** Can the Community Bulletins on Main and Meta have the same ordering of events, for the sake of consistency?

---

I'll add that there is an [old related feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236744/313042) asking for the "Featured on Meta" section to list the featured MSE posts on the Community Bulletins on per-site metas as well. The screenshots above show this difference too.